# Created nested list grouped by parent id

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following array that I want to group together in a nested list (ul) based upon the parent id matching the productSectionId.

```
"sections": [
       {
           "productSectionId": 9,
           "parentId": null,
           "name": "First Option"
       },
       {
           "productSectionId": 10,
           "parentId": 9,
           "name": "Sub First Option 1"
       },
       {
           "productSectionId": 11,
           "parentId": 9,
           "name": "Sub First Option 2"
       },
       {
           "productSectionId": 12,
           "parentId": null,
           "name": "Second Option"
       },
       {
           "productSectionId": 13,
           "parentId": 12,
           "name": "Sub Second Option 1"
       },
       {
           "productSectionId": 14,
           "parentId": 12,
           "name": "Sub Second Option 2"
       },
       {
           "productSectionId": 15,
           "parentId": 12,
           "name": "Sub Second Option 3"
       },
       {
           "productSectionId": 16,
           "parentId": 12,
           "name": "Sub Second Option 4"
       }

   ]
```

So basically like this...

- First Option
- Sub First Option 1
- Sub First Option 2
- Second Option
- Sub Second Option 1

...and so on

I can't rely on the order the array comes in and I'm not entirely sure on what is the best way to achieve this, so I have started out by grouping them together using lodash like this...

```
var grouped = _(products)
      .groupBy((x) => x.parentId)
      .map((value, key) => ({ parentId: key, products: value }))
      .value();
```

...which gives me 3 separate arrays consisting of the parentId and then another array with my items in.

I'm not sure where to go from here to create my nested list and whether my lodash approach is necessarily the correct one.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to group the products like you already did. Then use a recursive function to create the the structure you are looking for.

This does assume that the structure is a tree (there are no circular dependencies).

```js
const products = [{"productSectionId":9,"parentId":null,"name":"First Option"},{"productSectionId":10,"parentId":9,"name":"Sub First Option 1"},{"productSectionId":11,"parentId":9,"name":"Sub First Option 2"},{"productSectionId":12,"parentId":null,"name":"Second Option"},{"productSectionId":13,"parentId":12,"name":"Sub Second Option 1"},{"productSectionId":14,"parentId":12,"name":"Sub Second Option 2"},{"productSectionId":15,"parentId":12,"name":"Sub Second Option 3"},{"productSectionId":16,"parentId":12,"name":"Sub Second Option 4"}];

const grouped = _.groupBy(products, product => product.parentId);

function childrenOf(partenId) {
  return (grouped[partenId] || []).map(product => ({
    id: product.productSectionId,
    name: product.name,
    products: childrenOf(product.productSectionId)
  }));
}

console.log(childrenOf(null));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```